# Spannable Text is not working in Dialog Fragment

Tags: android, textview, android-dialogfragment, spannablestring

I have added `TextView` in my `Dialog` Fragment and i show **Spannable** data Dynamically in this `TextView`. But it's not apply **Spannable** effect to the text.

Here is my code to generate Three Spannable String and added into TextView.

```
 TextView  textViewTicketSummary = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.ticketSummaryTextView);
 SpannableStringBuilder summary = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    SpannableString VehicleCaptureSpan, TotalVehicleSpan, DurationTimeSpan;

    String VehicleCapture = "Total Vehicles Captured:9";
    VehicleCaptureSpan = new SpannableString(VehicleCapture);
    VehicleCaptureSpan.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, VehicleCapture.length(), 0);
    VehicleCaptureSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, VehicleCapture.length(), 0);
    VehicleCaptureSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, VehicleCapture.length(), 0);

    String TotalVehicle = "Total Car Park Capacity:10 ";
    TotalVehicleSpan = new SpannableString(TotalVehicle);
    TotalVehicleSpan.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, TotalVehicle.length(), 0);
    TotalVehicleSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, TotalVehicle.length(), 0);
    TotalVehicleSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, TotalVehicle.length(), 0);

    String DurationTime = "Total Duration: 0 Min 3 Secs ";
    DurationTimeSpan = new SpannableString(DurationTime);
    DurationTimeSpan.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, DurationTime.length(), 0);
    DurationTimeSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, DurationTime.length(), 0);
    DurationTimeSpan.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 0, DurationTime.length(), 0);

    summary.append(VehicleCapture).append("\n\n")
            .append(TotalVehicle).append("\n\n")
            .append(DurationTime).append("\n");

    textViewTicketSummary.setText(summary, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

### Here is my Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/shape_dialog_patrol"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="8dp" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/dialogOneButtonMessage"
    style="@style/OneButtonDialogBody"
    android:text="Dialog Body" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/ticketSummaryTextView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_textview_rounded_lightblack"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="4dp"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:text="Ticket Details"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialogOneButtonText"
        style="@style/OneButtonDialogButton2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/ok" />
   </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

### Here is the Output:

[image]

Please give me some hint..Why it's not working in `Dialog Fragment`?

Comment: Why are you using `0` flag (the last argument of `setSpan()`? You should probably use one of the predefined flags. As far as I can see, you should use `Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE`.

Comment: @shoerat Ok wait let me try....

Comment: summary.append(VehicleCapture).append("\n\n")
            .append(TotalVehicle).append("\n\n")
            .append(DurationTime).append("\n"); has to be
summary.append(VehicleCaptureSpan).append("\n\n")
            .append(TotalVehicleSpan).append("\n\n")
            .append(DurationTimeSpan).append("\n");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve this you should specify the type of `Span`. You can set it in fourth parameter of `setSpan()` method. In your case the value should be [SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html#SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE):

> Spans of type SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE do not expand to include text inserted at either their starting or ending point. They can never have a length of 0 and are automatically removed from the buffer if all the text they cover is removed.

Like this:

```
VehicleCaptureSpan.setSpan(
        new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
        0,
        VehicleCapture.length(),
        Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
);
```

But if you want to set color or text style of whole text it is easier to set them with `TextView` parameters:

```
textViewTicketSummary.setTextColor(Color.RED);
textViewTicketSummary.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, size);
textViewTicketSummary.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
```

**UPD:**
There is a small funny bug in your code. You are trying to append `String`s instead of `SpannableString` values to builder. Just change that code to this one:

```
summary.append(VehicleCaptureSpan).append("\n\n")
        .append(TotalVehicleSpan).append("\n\n")
        .append(DurationTimeSpan).append("\n");
```

Comment: I'll try your solution by tomorrow.

Comment: @MD I find a small bug in your code. See my updated answer please.